# Asp.net Session state Trying to keep contents of textbox when returned to page

Tags: c#, asp.net

ive two pages, one with a text box and a button, the other with a button a label. What i want to do is to display contents of the textbox on page 1, in the label of the page2 on button click. and then when i click the button to return to page1. preverse whats entered in the textbox on page1. sorry if its confusing. heres my code

page1.aspx

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

 {      
 Session["fstName"] = txtBox.Text;
 Response.Redirect("Page2.aspx");
  }
```

page2.aspx

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string a = Session["fstName"].ToString();
        lblPage2.Text = a;
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("WebForm1.aspx");
    }
```

Comment: From the looks of it, this should work. What error are you getting?

Comment: no error just textbox empty when I return to page1

Comment: Any chance you have turned off session state in web.config? `<sessionState mode="Off">` or on the page? `EnableSessionState="false"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you set the value of the text box when returning to `WebForm1.aspx`?  It should be very similar to what you have for the label on `Page2.aspx`.  Something like:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string a = Session["fstName"].ToString();
    txtBox.Text = a;
}
```

At worst, you may need to wrap some error checking around it.  Maybe something like:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
        if (Session["fstName"] != null)
        {
            string a = Session["fstName"].ToString();
            txtBox.Text = a;
        }
}
```

Comment: I didnt think I had to set the value on return. i thought that was what session state was for? and is it possible to add put "string a = Session["fstName"].ToString(); lblPage2.Text = a; into the button click on page 1 or does it have go into the pageload on page 2? sorry if im confusing you

Comment: @FrancisGall: Session state holds the value in a stateful server-side context, but it doesn't automatically populate controls with that value.  In your second page, you had to explicitly get the value from session state and set it to the control's text.  Why would the control on the first page be any different?  When a page loads, if there are values in session state which need to be on that page, you need to get them from session state and put them on the page.

Comment: @FrancisGall: You can't set a control on a page from another page, no.  Each time a request is made for a page, that page object is created, initialized, processed with any code you have on it, sent to the user, and then destroyed.  When one page loads, no other page exists.